# I am trying to hit Sabre Fare Rule soap api on postman but it's giving error errors.xml.USG_INVALID_ACTION, How to resolve it

Tags: laravel, soap-client, sabre, ota, fare

Here is my request body

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Base64_token
        </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <OTA_AirRulesRQ ReturnHostCommand="true" Version="2.3.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
            <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="12-24">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHE"/>
                <MarketingCarrier Code="AA"/>
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="DXB"/>
            </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <RuleReqInfo>
            <FareBasis Code="Y"/>
        </RuleReqInfo>
    </OTA_AirRulesRQ>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`
```

Here is the error i am getting, how can i fix it.USG_INVALID_ACTION means the format error but i didn'r understand what is format issue in my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">T1RLAQLmuWgGgRgzvWBSZcj2/EuqJCuoqC1hqaF0JFHKYQ+GlRA/190rlR3HglH9lxLudMWoAADQAnrngzMgfJAC3ippxepcykrjbucnnl8Azsk3fgQ1/xsNddLLvmJygXnPSyaS/z4uL/BCoClQDlS8Rq9vbhOIevpCG9jpBT4557sXBDONTKaAedt5uv+2RRA/7gwRcDkH3AOyoxifi6raxDPHntzq9TUgO0sEuah2+WM6f2isg095CUPPdJbYXMwXFyM/xaWgRAIuwrxP24Cnr9bJyEVeS0YzNrK0qSu+zcdW5oAb6KT1IeQSOl1rHG1FafST9TqcLem+LkF6Ah3o3BWKBJXSZw**
        </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <soap-env:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap-env:Client.InvalidAction</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.ApplicationException: errors.xml.USG_INVALID_ACTION</StackTrace>
            </detail>
        </soap-env:Fault>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Sabre postman collection, the action is taken from the name of the request.

From the ZPre-request Script:

```
const action = request.name.split(' ')[0].replace(/^_|[0-9]./, '');
```

So your request must be named something like `OTA_AirRulesLLSRQ 2.3.0` to work.